# BeautifulSoup selector returning empty list

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

First of all, I'm new to web scraping, so if my jargon is off, I apologize. I'm trying to get four items (movie title, runtime, genre, and year) into a Pandas DF from this IMDB Top 1000 movies site. I'm following along with a tutorial (https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-python-using-beautiful-soup/) that first breaks the process down so that you extract a single element from a list of HTML elements (in this case one movie) and get the desired attributes (movie title, runtime, genre, and year) using HTML tags. However, when I try to continue along with the tutorial and use a selector to get all of the elements under the main tag from all movies, I end up with an empty list.

So here is the first part of the process (extract a single element from a list of HTML elements and get the desired attributes for that one element (movie):

```
# Let's get the html from https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_1000&sort=runtime,asc. 
# We’ll need to first download it using the requests.get method.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl

page = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_1000&sort=runtime,asc")

# create an instance of the BeautifulSoup class to parse our document
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

top_1000 = soup.find(id = "main") # Find outermost element containing all relevant movie info 
film_items = top_1000.find_all(class_='lister-item mode-advanced') # Get the element containing the list of films
first_film = film_items[0]     # Get first film in list
print(first_film.prettify())

tags = first_film.find_all('a') # Get all <a tags
title = tags[1].text # Title is embedded in the second item in this list
genre = first_film.find(class_='genre').get_text() 
year = first_film.find(class_="lister-item-year text-muted unbold").get_text() 
runtime = first_film.find(class_="runtime").get_text() 

print(title)
print(genre)
print(year)
print(runtime)
```

OUTPUT:

Sherlock Jr.

Action, Comedy, Romance
(1924)

45 min

BUT...when I use a selector to get data for all of the films, it returns an empty list

```
# Select all items with the class genre inside an item with the class lister-item mode-advanced in top_1000.
# Use a list comprehension to call the get_text method on each BeautifulSoup object.
genre = top_1000.select(".lister-item mode-advanced .genre")
genres = [g.get_text() for g in genre]
print(genres)
```

OUTPUT:

[]

I thought perhaps I have to include each nested element when calling the selector, but I tried calling the element nested immediately below "lister-item mode-advanced" and it also returned an empty list. In fact, when I only include "lister-item mode-advanced" in the selector, I get a blank list. I followed along with the tutorial verbatim, but this does not seem to be working. I would appreciate any help with this, and again, I apologize for any language discrepancies--I'm new to working with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A class name can’t have spaces. When you have a space-separated string in your class attribute - it means it has several classes.

So an element like:

```
<div class="lister-item mode-advanced"></div>
```

will have the classes `lister-item` and `mode-advanced`.

You can reference multiple classes using dot syntax, like `.lister-item.mode-advanced`

Try this:

```
genre = top_1000.select(".lister-item.mode-advanced .genre")
genres = [g.get_text().strip() for g in genre]
print(genres)
```

```
['Action, Comedy, Romance', 'Drama, Horror', 'Action, Adventure, Comedy', 'Comedy, Drama, Family', 'Comedy, Musical, War', 'Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi', 'Horror, Sci-Fi', 'Animation, Adventure, Family', 'Comedy, Romance', 'Animation, Sci-Fi', 'Drama, History, Thriller', 'Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi', 'Fantasy, Horror, Mystery', 'Animation, Action, Crime', 'Animation, Family, Fantasy', 'Animation, Adventure, Family', 'Comedy', 'Crime, Drama, Mystery', 'Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Animation, Comedy, Drama', 'Drama, Romance', 'Animation, Adventure, Comedy', 'Crime, Drama, Thriller', 'Animation, Crime, Mystery', 'Animation, Comedy, Fantasy', 'Comedy, Music', 'Comedy, Fantasy, Romance', 'Animation, Family, Fantasy', 'Animation, Action, Crime', 'Crime, Drama, Film-Noir', 'Comedy, Horror', 'Animation, Family, Fantasy', 'Drama, Thriller, Western', 'Drama, Thriller', 'Comedy, War', 'Comedy, Crime', 'Comedy, Drama, Family', 'Crime, Mystery, Thriller', 'Drama, Romance', 'Animation, Family, Fantasy', 'Animation, Action, Adventure', 'Drama, Music, Romance', 'Comedy, Horror', 'Comedy, Drama, Romance', 'Comedy, Drama, Family', 'Comedy, Musical', 'Action, Crime, Comedy', 'Animation, Action, Drama']
```

Note: I've also added [.strip()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) method that gets rid of any leading and trailing spaces, since your raw 'genre' data looks like the following:

```
'\nAction, Comedy, Romance            '
```

Comment: Thank you! That's super helpful. How would I get the titles (e.g., Sherlock Jr.) from HTML code with a href?  --> <a href="/title/tt0015324/?ref_=adv_li_tt">Sherlock Jr.</a>

Comment: @j.c.hayes82 Here's a one-liner:
`print([s.find('a').get_text() for s in top_1000.select(".lister-item-header")])`